# SQL Server WHERE clause using Week and year

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that will query a table based on WEEK and YEAR but I want the WHERE clause to include an offset of the current date's week and year. I want the offset to be 8 weeks forward of the current date.

Normally this is not an issue as I can simply do a BETWEEN in the WHERE clause, but when we get to the end of a year like week 50 and 8 weeks forward would be week 6 of the following year. So I need a WHERE clause that can treat this time of year differently. I'm unsure how to construct this, is there a way to have one WHERE clause that can handle the same year as well as spanning between two years?

Here's what it looks like at the outset for me to get the weeks I want from my table:

```
DECLARE @startweek int;
DECLARE @endweek int;
DECLARE @startyear int;
DECLARE @endyear int;

SET @startweek = DatePart(week,getdate())
SET @startyear = DatePart(year,getdate())
SET @endweek = DatePart(week,DateAdd(week,8,getdate()))
SET @endyear = DatePart(year,DateAdd(week,8,getdate()))

SELECT * from SomeTable st
WHERE st.week between @startweek and @endweek
```

--you can suppose that SomeTable has week, year, order_number, customer fields in the table

(The above would work for weeks in the database that fall in the same year, but not if @startweek = 50 and @endweek = 8. How would I write this to handle either scenerio?  Thanks!)

Comment: What are the other date/time related columns in `SomeTable`? Surely you don't just have a `week` column and a `year` and nothing else? Does it not have an `OrderDate` column somewhere?

Comment: Ok, so no, no `OrderDate` column. Who records just the year and week # an event took place? Well, bad design = bad queries I guess. :-\

Comment: I work for a shipping company and we have vessel/voyages that travel on certain weeks, so an actual date is not necessary, the vessel sails on the week number, so that is why I only have the week and year field in my data. I made the question resemble an order system just for ease of understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume in addition to `st.week`, you also have `st.year`.   If you only have `st.week`, it's easy.  Either way, one way is to use a forked WHERE clause.

In psuedocode,

```
WHERE (
  @startyear = @endyear   --same year
  AND st.week BETWEEN @startweek and @endweek
  AND st.year = @startyear
) OR (
  @startyear < @endyear  --spans the end of year
  AND (
    st.week > @startweek AND st.year = @startyear
  ) OR (
    st.week < @endweek AND st.year = @endyear
  )
)
```

If your table doesn't have a `year` column, then simply remove the bits that reference it from the above.

Comment: My table has (week, year, order_number, customer, qty) It does not have a date at all, just week and year.

Comment: Tab, Yes, your's works. I was thinking it was something like this but I was trying to put it in a CASE statement in the WHERE and just couldn't figure it out, thanks so much for your solution!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
DECLARE @startweek INT = 50;
DECLARE @endweek int;
DECLARE @startyear INT = 2018;
DECLARE @endyear int;

SELECT 
    @endweek = DATEPART(WEEK, ed.enddate),
    @endyear = DATEPART(YEAR, ed.enddate)
FROM
    ( VALUES (DATEADD(WEEK, @startweek, DATEFROMPARTS(@startyear, 1, 1))) ) sd (startdate)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (DATEADD(WEEK, 8, sd.startdate)) ) ed (enddate)


SELECT 
    startweek = @startweek,
    endweek  = @endweek,
    startyear = @startyear,
    endyear   = @endyear;
```

Results...

```
startweek   endweek     startyear   endyear
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
50          7           2018        2019
```

Comment: No, I am after the records in my table that fall between the week range your results show. I have a week field and year field in my table along with other data and I just want to return the records that fall within the 8 weeks that could span across two years.